# Assumed mode method to solve problems

Tags: differential-equations, vibrations

I am trying to understand part 4 (Approximate analytical solution to pull-in voltage) of this paper, "An approximate analytical solution to the pull-in voltage of a micro bridge with an elastic boundary", which can be found here: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0960-1317/17/9/016

In this part of the paper, they solve a rather complex equation by making use of the so-called **assumed mode method**, which was developped  in vibrational analysis. As I am a novice in this field, I am having difficulties finding the right sources to understand the mechanisme of this method.

Therefore, I would highly appreciate any explanation with a simple example of this method and of course any references to good explanations on the web.